# When and how to use Aggregate Target in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, aggregate, target

I was trying to look for an example of using an Aggregate Target in Xcode4, including its purpose and why a developer should use it.

Do you have any reference link, especially from Apple Developer web site?

Answer (score 15):

> **Aggregate Target**
>
> Xcode defines a special type of target that lets you build a group of
> targets at once, even if those targets do not depend on each other. An
> aggregate target has no associated product and no build rules.
> Instead, an aggregate target depends on each of the targets you want
> to build together. For example, you may have a group of products that
> you want to build together. You would create an aggregate target and
> make it depend on each of the product targets. To build all the
> products, just build the aggregate target.
>
> An aggregate target may contain a custom Run Script build phase or a
> Copy Files build phase, but it cannot contain any other build phases.
> Any build settings that the aggregate target contains are not
> interpreted but are passed to the build phases that the target
> contains.

*[**Source**](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/100-Targets/bs_targets.html)*

Answer (score 5):

One reason I use an aggregate target is to package up my application into a .dmg or .zip for distribution.  I set the application's target as a dependency, then run a script phase.  You could also build and run other tools that either modify the app or help with the packaging, etc.

Comment: Ah... Can you please elaborate on how to integrate this with Xcode "Archiving" ? I do exactly what you claim here - but since I need to use the "Archive" build-step for correctly sign my components, and installer package and the .dmg containing it - I'd like my stuff to be correctly archived too.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode aggregate target**

An `aggregate` target does not **directly** generate a build product. This target does not have `Build Rules`, but it has `Build Phase` with `Dependencies`, `Copy Files Phase` and `Run Script Phase`. It can help you to manage other targets to build a product. This target can be a dependency of other target or can be called outside via a related schema.

For example `aggregate` target is used to create a `Universal framework`, `Umbrella framework`, [auto-versionning](https://blog.twitch.tv/en/2016/09/20/ios-versioning-89e02f0a5146/), [embedding frameworks in iMessage apps with Xcode 8.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1936/_index.html)

To create `aggregate` target

```
New Target -> Cross-platform -> Aggregate
```

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)
[[Read more about Xcode structure]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)