# Building pure Swift Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode6

I'm exploring Swift with Xcode-6 and so far so good although I think the new collections need a little bit of work as I've managed to break the compiler a few times.

Problem is I'm now stuck trying to create the framework package to ***then use in another project***. The project builds without issue and all tests pass successfully.  When I go to create Archive (which I assume is what is required) I receive the error:

> :0: error: underlying Objective-C module 'Sample' not found

Now I assume this has something to do with the contents of my Sample.h which tells me

```
// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <Sample/PublicHeader.h>
```

which is fine except I have only used swift enums, structs and classes for this framework so therefore no .h files exist.

Can anyone shed some light on this one as I can't find any documentation available yet?

Comment: Why Archive framework?

Comment: Have you tried to build a pure swift framework project and use that from a client app in the same workspace? If so, did it work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*EDIT (7/27/2018)*

The information in the answer below may no longer be accurate. Your mileage may vary.

---

I sat down with an engineer and asked this exact question. This was their response:

Xcode 6 does not support building distributable Swift frameworks at this time and that Apple likely won't build this functionality into Xcode until its advantageous for them to do so. Right now, Frameworks are meant to be embedded in your app's project, rather than distributed. If you watch any of the session videos or see the sample projects, this is always the arrangement. [Another reason is that Swift is very new and likely to change. Thus your Swift-based framework is not guaranteed to work on the platform you originally built it on.](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2)

**Slight Update**

The engineer mentioned that it's not impossible to make a framework for distribution, just that it's not supported.

Comment: This is in direct conflict with Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Those docs are still "pre-release" so it's subject to change Also, they didn't say it wasn't possible to build a framework and use it in a separate project. They just said it wasn't supported. Have you tried building a Swift Framework target for use in a different project?

Comment: Yes, I was keeping my powder dry and trying to find the boundaries of what does and doesn't work, but it's all working fine at the moment. I suspect the following constraints (at least) exist: If they revise the swift language, despite the promised binary compatibility, the application and all of its frameworks will have to be built using the same binary version.

Comment: Are we sure that iOS Swift Frameworks are not supported now that Xcode 6 is released? I can't find onfirmation in the docs/notes.  It is an option in XCode for Frameworks.  For anyone interested, here is a step by step of how I'm setting up my project.  Is this wrong? https://github.com/mikemoser/swift-framework

Comment: @MichaelMoser They are supported, but only as a framework that is a part of a single project. What's not natively supported is breaking that framework off to use it in some other project (see the OP's second paragraph, first sentence) or distribute it to someone.

Comment: I just get that "Use of undeclared type", "use of unresolved identifier", error, no matter what I try with a Swift Cocoa Touch Framework. I have tried an enclosing workspace. I have tried adding the framework project as a subproject. I have tried importing the framework directly from "Link Binary With Libraries". Its December now.. Is this supported or not?

Comment: @Michael Moser,  thank you for sharing your framework example. It works when I use it in a separate project. I have an issue if I add Swift files of my own to a copy of it, build, then add to a sample project. Even declared publicly, they are of "undeclared type".

Comment: @Aaron, Still can't we make distributed framework in Swift ?, Swift got +1 year older now. :-(

Comment: @ZaidPathan I haven't tried since this original question. The situation may have changed, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Aaron, I guess still there is no way, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to get past the error by going to the target for the framework and on the Build Phases tab under Headers, remove the MyFramework.h file

However I was getting the "Underlying Objective-C module not found" error when I was using a framework to share code between a containing app and an app extension, both of which were pure Swift.

[image: Image showing MyFramework.h for the MyFramework target on the Build Phases tab under Headers]

Comment: This helped me with the same issue. Although it doesn't really tell me what was wrong ... anyways, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are creating a truly pure Swift module, you must disable the Objective-C Compatibility Header and any generated interface headers so the compiler doesn't go off assuming it can find an Objective-C module for the framework. [image]

**Do Not** remove your public framework header.  You'll get a module-map warning at link time if you do.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this useful: [Creation of pure swift module](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/26/creation-of-pure-swift-module)

In short: it's possible to make static framework, but there is one issue: it doesn't work in end user' project if "ProjectName-Swift.h" header included.

But, it works fine if you use only swift.

Comment: Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in XCode 6, or that Apple does not allow archiving the Framework from XCode while in beta.

If you compile to profile XCode generates the framework correctly. (See the Release folder created in DerivedData)