# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, linker, ios8, xcode6

I had set up my application using static library initially but I am trying to use the cocoa touch framework of iOS 8 in the application. I have created the framework and moved all the files from static library to the framework, my build fails with this error

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_DataReader", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in device.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have made sure that all the necessary header files are included in the framework and they are public. I have linked my framework under the link binary with Libraries. I have tried removing arm64 from the valid architectures as some posts suggested but no luck. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting the **iOS Simulator**. From personal experience, frameworks are apparently not fully supported on the simulator. It's hard to provide any concrete evidence regarding this, since there doesn't seem to be any relevant documentation. Also, according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24072626/2747515), distribution of frameworks shouldn't even be supported (might've changed for the GM seed).

To get your framework working:

- Change the build destination to **iOS Device**.
- Clean project.
- Build project.

That's all you need to do.