# "error: underlying Objective-C module <module> not found"

Tags: ios, dynamic, swift, module, frameworks

With the release of iOS 8 and Xcode 6, it is now possible to build dynamic iOS frameworks. It seems that Apple *still* hasn't documented this topic as of yet, leaving developers to fend for themselves against the deadly, cryptic errors of Xcode, one particularly nasty:

```
"error: underlying Objective-C module <module> not found"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apple does not promote distribution of iOS frameworks as of Xcode 6 ([referring to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24072626/2747515)):

> Xcode 6 does not support building distributable Swift frameworks at
>   this time and that Apple likely won't build this functionality into
>   Xcode until its advantageous for them to do so.

However, it is not impossible to build one:

- Go to the **Product** menu.
- Click on **Build For**.
- Select **Testing**.

And as always, trashing Xcode's `DerivedData` folder (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`) usually solves any trivial problems that may arise.

Comment: That post was from before Beta 2 (think it was beta 2) which added support for frameworks.  I have had this error intermittently and have had to restart XCode and do a clean build to get around it.  In short, this has been an intermittent problem for me.

Comment: And, still in 6.1 also.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this issue.  If you are importing a module that links any Objective-C frameworks, you need to import those Objective-C frameworks in your module too.  That shouldn't add to your bundle size if you are not using a static library.

I imported all of the frameworks needed for Parse into one module "Module A".  In order to import "Module A" into "Module B", I had to add all of the required Parse frameworks and "Module A" to my Linked Libraries for "Module B".