# Using swift framework as subproject in Obj-C application

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have an objective-c application in which I want to use a swift framework I created myself. The framework built fine and all tests are green. However I have now trouble to use it in my application. I added the framework as a subproject to the application, ensured that `Defines Module` is enabled as well as `Embeds Swift Code` and set the framework as dependency for the app (and added it to a copy build phase for my other frameworks). Still I cannot use it. Some observations:

1. In my app I have **development** and **release** builds. The framework however uses **debug** and **release**. I haven't adjusted that manually, it's the default. I don't know if that plays a role here.
2. The framework is built, but as **release**, even though I build a
   **development** version of my app.
3. The framework-Swift.h header is created by XCode in that release intermediate folder, but is not accessible from any obj-c file. It's simply not found. I renamed the release folder to development, just as a test, but to no avail.

The application itself also contains some swift code and hence everything is set up there properly (including the 2 bridging headers). I could add only the swift files from my framework to the app project, but somehow this defeats the purpose of a framework, right.

So what do I have to do to:

1. Build the correct target (development vs release)?
2. Make the generated Swift header available in the app?

I certainly don't want to add a header search path to the intermediate folder in the project settings. I don't need to for the other generated header.

Comment: The suggestion here is that what you're trying to do may be impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070726/building-pure-swift-cocoa-touch-framework

Comment: Note the difference: I added the framework as subproject, which should perfectly be possible, only the use as compiled framework may make problems (though some of the comments say it would work).