# Import framework for whole project at one place in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I made an own `Cocoa Touch Framework`, and I want to import it only at one place in the code. In Xcode / earlier in Objective C there were a central location under `Supporting Files`. How does it work for Swift based project?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: no, I am importing in each file

Comment: I tried adding in Embedded frameworks and linked frameworks, didn't work to my surprise.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Frameworks folder. Drag and drop your framework in it. Then create a bridging header file (easiest way to do this in Swift project is by adding an objective c class and it will ask you to create that bridging file for you). Then in your bridging header file just add

```
#import <YourFramework/YourFramework.h>
```

Then your framework classes are accessible from Swift. Hope this helps!

Comment: is this for `Cocoa Touch Framework` not static library, and Swift? Because my file / class in framework has .swift extension

Comment: Apologies Janos, I thought your framework is Objective C based and you want to integrate it in your Swift project. I think Swift Frameworks are currently not supported, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070726/building-pure-swift-cocoa-touch-framework because Swift is quite new and bound to change.

Comment: it was active 6 month ago

Comment: I had a play and this worked for me - add your Swift framework to your project. Then in your project target -> Build Phases add your framework as a Target Dependencie. Then whenever you need to use your swift files just do 'import YourFrameworkName' and declare your class object

Answer (score 0):

As I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878808/3203441

As of Swift4:

- Being in a Swift project
- Want to have another Swift project globally imported (and using cocoapods)

I just managed to do that by adding the following line to my bridging header:

```
#import <PodName/PodName-Swift.h>
```

How good/bad this practise is? Not sure, but I just wanted some extensions globally available in my project. this did the trick.