# How to import a Swift framework globally?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a way to import my Swift Cocoapods globally in every class, how can I achieve this?

I tried a lot of things and they didn't work. Here are some ways I haven't tried and thought may be possible if found a way to work them:

Have a general import statement like UIKit and put everything in there. (Edit: This failed)

Somehow put Swift frameworks in the Obj-C briding header and import the stuff in there.

Comment: Yes, use a bridging header. This question may be a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162622/import-framework-for-whole-project-at-one-place-in-swift

Comment: Actually apparently that answer was never accepted, so that may not work... I think the answer may be that you cannot do this in swift. You need to import to every file that's using the framework, sorry.

Comment: OP, what's stopping you from accepting the answer?
@prolfe unfortunately there is no way around this and that's the good way - code is available only where it's needed, so it enables to compile / run everything quicker

Comment: People are interested in this question and I still think/hope there is some kind of hack to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 58):

You should be able to import it globally by adding @_exported before the import.

```
@_exported import MyPodModuleName
```

However, like the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969266/8740349) mentions, doing that for an entire module is not recommended, because it introduces implicit coupling between modules.

Hence instead try something like:

```swift
import Foundation

@_exported import class MyModuleName.MyClassName
@_exported import class MyModuleName.MyOtherClass
```

Comment: but how can i write in project ...like appdelegate or anyview controller

Answer (score 46):

It's strongly discouraged in Swift because that would introduce implicit coupling between modules.

However, you can make a certain symbol available globally by declaring a `typealias` in the module that imports the other module:

```
import ModuleName
public typealias ClassName = ModuleName.ClassName
```

Comment: 100% loosely coupled components exist only in theory. There are always some global library dependencies across the whole project. For example, a custom logger with log levels would be a good example. Therefore typealias perfectly fits in such cases.

Comment: I was doing above but was forced to switch to `@_exported`, because Swift's compile bug --- try Cuckoo lib's "Mock" feature with a method returning type-alias to see what I mean.

Answer (score 19):

As of Swift4:

- Being in a Swift project
- Want to have another Swift project globally
  imported (and using cocoapods)

I just managed to do that by adding the following line to my bridging header:

```
#import <PodName/PodName-Swift.h>
```

How good/bad this practise is? Not sure, but I just wanted some extensions globally available in my project. this did the trick.

Comment: Interesting "hack" importing the auto generated .h in bridging header. But there is a limitation as the .h only include `@objc` and `NSObject` subclasses in the Swift module; it does not include the pure Swift stuff.

Answer (score 8):

There is **no** way to do this. And this is not a bug, this is a language feature (so far, as speaking of Swift 2.2).

Swift uses **modules** (Apple introduced them in Xcode 5 for Objective-C) and each file is an semantic unit, so you need to explicitly inform Xcode which modules are exposed to defined file.

Not only there is no support for your described behaviour, but you shouldn't also try to bypass it. Using unnecessary (unused) modules could theoretically produce slower code (taking into account that compiler uses this information to its optimisation process).

Comment: Furthermore (or "randomly"), Xcode might magically get knowledge of one of your frameworks for your Swift files, but AppCode will be utterly confused. You need to do you `import` on each Swift file in the framework client.

Comment: @Krodak Do you happen to have an apple link where this gets mentioned? I strongly agree with you but i would really like some form of indication from apple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually achieve the same functionality by:

- Creating the [Objective-C Bridging Header file](https://mycodetips.com/ios/manually-adding-swift-bridging-header-1290.html);
- Adding `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to the Objective-C Bridging Header file (so that you don't need to repeat this for every single .swift file).

for pods you have to do like `#import <SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON-umbrella.h>`

Answer (score 0):

**A** reason you wouldn't want to do this:

Imagine if both your frameworks would use *the same method name*, it would make things ambiguous for the compiler.The compiler won't know which method it should run.

To find out more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736698/swift-extension-same-extension-function-in-two-modules) question