# Importing Module For All Files in Module - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, import, module

Is there anyway in swift to import a module for all files in a module quickly in a swift?

For example: 
I am using Firebase and I had to `import Firebase` in all the places I needed to use Firebase API.

I want to import it once and then use throughout the module.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460330/how-to-import-a-swift-framework-globally It may be helpful. Basically it is not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a Swift framework globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460330/how-to-import-a-swift-framework-globally)