# Is there a way to import once (or not import) a CocoaPod Framework in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've build a `Pod` library called `UsefulExtensions`. It's a framework written in `Swift 3` which adds some useful class variable and functions to standard classes and types like `UIView` or `String`.
Everything worked perfectly, and my framework is accessible from everywhere in the workspace. 
The problem is that I have to import it everywhere I use it.

Is there a way to make my functions visible without import my framework?

If not, is there an elegant way to import only once my framework for the whole project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a Swift framework globally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460330/how-to-import-a-swift-framework-globally)

Comment: Yes and no, because my framework contains extensions vars and functions, so it could be better if I don't have to import it at all. Maybe I should change something in my framework config, I don't know...

Comment: Maybe instead of a framework you could consider making a custom project template: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-custom-xcode-templates it could include an extensions group with all your code, and since it's in the scope of the current project you won't have to import on each file, or you could add these extensions as a git submodule: https://www.google.com/amp/s/idevzilla.com/2015/09/21/git-submodule-tutorial-cocoapods-might-not-be-the-solution/amp/

Comment: Thank you, I think that the first solution could be the best one, @MathewS !