# Build Xcode 6 Cocoa Touch Framework project

Tags: frameworks, xcode6

Here are the steps I have done:

I created a Cocoa Touch Framework project, added a class TestClass. build the project, and examined the Derived Data directory, show content of .framework, there is binary file, Headers directory and Info.plist, However I could not find TestClass.h in Headers. Am I missing anything, how to expose TestClass.h? Can anyone show the steps of building framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project **Build Phases** > **Headers**, then drag the headers you intent to expose to public from **Project** to **Public**.

I have written steps to create framework project, you can find it in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039470/xcode-6-ios-creating-a-cocoa-touch-framework-architectures-issues/24295122#24295122).

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 6, select the project then **Build Phases > Copy Files** then add the resources or header files you want included in the subpath or include folder.

You may want to watch: [How to create a Cocoa Touch Static Library video](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-cocoa-touch-static-library-using-xcode/)