# Has anybody upgraded existing Universal Framework for iOS 8 and Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, ios-universal-framework

There appear to be lots of people having issues since Apple's updates to support Universal Frameworks in their latest release.  We have been using Universal Frameworks for quite some time.  Of course, the update broke our Universal Frameworks and I have been trying to figure out how to get them to work again.  I have looked at a few questions and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24039470/1735836) to be exceptionally helpful.  There appears to be some confusion regarding whether scripts are still needed.  I found some instructions [here](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework#mk-8-is-now-out-of-beta) that say the new scripts are python scripts instead of shell scripts.  But even with the information I have found out there, I am still confused.

Can anyone give me clear consise steps to convert an existing Universal Framework into one that compiles and builds in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 2):

We are also facing similar issue when we upgraded to xcode6 and haven't found any solution so we decided to use apple ios custom cocoa touch framework .Below is the tutorial for  building frameworks using xcode 6.

http://rescueprogramming.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-create-custom-cocoa-touch.html

Answer (score -1):

We have written up a step by step guide on how to implement and integrate Xcode Frameworks that describes:

1) How to create an Xcode 6 Cocoa Touch Framework.

2) How to create a dependent Xcode 6 Cocoa Touch Framework.

3) How to Integrate your working Xcode 6 Frameworks and dependent Frameworks into an iOS application.

This step-by-step instruction guide can be found here:

https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios-8/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Can you list the main points please directly in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: -1? -- that's pretty brutal seeing as how these instructions are exactly what this person was seeking. -- is there any way to remove this helpful information?  We don't have time to repost to blog here, and certainly aren't interested in negative votes! -- please let us know how to remove our attempt to help. -- thank you!

Comment: No need to repost the all the details, but a rough outline of the main points would be great. The details can then be checked via the link.

Comment: Alrighty, Philip, we gave it shot! Thanks for the clarification. Happy hacking!