# framework not found AFNetworking for architecture x86_64 in my Cocoapods based custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I write a custom iOS swift framework in Xcode 6.3 and using Cocoapods as a dependency tool. I use some objective-c modules, ex. AFNetworking, FMDB... But when I take my .framework to other apps, they say:

```
ld: framework not found FMDB for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I run the unittests of my framework well, but cannot build it with my app which using my custom framework. I guess it's the issue from objective-c module I use in my framework. But I don't know how to set it in the right way. I provide my Podfile as follow:

```
use_frameworks!
link_with 'bdilogger', 'bdiloggerTests'
pod 'ProtocolBuffers-Swift'
pod 'FMDB', :git => 'https://github.com/robertmryan/fmdb.git'
pod "AFNetworking"
```

BTW, I find my .framework from Debug-iphonesimulator under derivedData, cause I didn't have a developer now so that I cannot build an iOS device version. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks for answering a lot.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device) answer.

Comment: I wrote an extensive guide on how to publish a universal binary iOS framework using CocoaPods: https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/