# Using a third party framework into a AppStore app pulls in the iPhoneSimulator bits

Tags: ios, frameworks, ipa

I am integrating a third party framework into my AppStore app using Xcode 6.4. The framework from the third party is a universal binary which has the following when I do the file command :

```
DeviceTester (for architecture i386):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
DeviceTester (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
DeviceTester (for architecture armv7):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
DeviceTester (for architecture arm64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library
```

I have tried adding this framework as a Embedded Binary. This works fine it build fine however when I upload the "ipa" to the AppStore, it complains of the ipa having unsupported architecture which are the simulator pieces. when I inspect the ipa file I do see a "Frameworks" folder as is with the universal framework inside it. But I don't see this for any of the other frameworks I including eg. Crashlytics/Fabric etc. So there is something incorrect here.

I also tried adding it as a framework and then made sure it is in the copy phase, but running it gives the following error on the device :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DeviceTester.framework/DeviceTester
 Referenced from: /var/mobil....
```

Any pointers gladly appreciated, I have spent the whole day today trying to figure out what is happening with no luck.. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

From [Xcode 6.1.1 & 6.2: iOS frameworks containing simulator slices can't be submitted to the App Store](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216). You would need to remove the simulator slices from the fat framework to be able to submit to the AppStore.

Here's a script to do the magic. Add a Run Script step to your build steps, put it after your step to embed frameworks, set it to use `/bin/sh` and enter the following script:

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

 # This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
 # removes unused architectures.
 find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
 do
     FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
     FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
     echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

This answer might explain what you are asking. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270427/4160199