# Archive upload failed using ReactiveCocoa.framework

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have created ReactiveCocoa.framework with Carthage and it works fine on my phone and simulator.
But when I uploaded it to the iTune Connect,there comes out an error
[image]

It seems that the imported ReactiveCocoa.frame don't support architectures 'x86_64,i386',So I use lipo tool to read the framework's supporting architectures
[image]

Comment: Could someone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .framework file is an "universal framework". It contains binaries built for the iOS device *and* the simulator (that's what "architectures 'x86_64, i386`" means).

And you can't submit a binary built for the simulator to the iTunes Connect. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270427/2128900), you have to "strip" the simulator architectures from the framework. As you use Carthage, you can use

`carthage copy-frameworks`

command. Use it in a script in "Build Phases", as describe in the Carthage [documentation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).