# Combined framework simulator/device binary Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I followed carefully [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device) for this

**In summary you have to use lipo to connect each `device` and `simulator` build**

*Using:*

```
lipo -create -output "MyFrameworkName" "Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameworkName.framework/MyFrameworkName" "Debug-iphoneos/MyFrameworkName.framework/MyFrameworkName"
```

I am choosing any framework `Debug-iphonesimulator` or `Debug-iphoneos` as a base to add the file that resulted from lipo.

Example:

[image]

> The problem is that no matter which of the 2 use as a base (`Debug-iphonesimulator` or `Debug-iphoneos`). If the base is the simulator when I add it to the parent project does not run on the device. and vice versa

It seems that `lipo` was not doing a good job uniting the 2 files, or missing some files more to join.

I have searched the web and apparently no more steps to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, just need drag and drop the file and using the native merge option displayed.

***"Native merge":***

[image]

Comment: what do you mean the native merge option? How can I do that?

Comment: Ah, thank you. You need to hold option while drag and drop. And you still need to lipo the binary.