# "Fat" Cocoa Touch Framework classes can't be found

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have a cocoa touch framework written in Swift. In order to distribute it, I built a fat binary based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650369/2362508).
It used to work fine up to xCode 7.

I'm trying to release a new version of my framework using the same solution. To test it, I integrated the framework to a Swift test project, but I get an error that my classes can't be found when I run on simulator, on the device works fine.

For both the `import "MyFramework"` is fine, it just seems that on simulator there aren't any classes in the framework.

Is anyone experiencing this issue, or have any idea of what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I searched further, and turns out I forgot there was another step that the solution didn't mention.

The framework folder that contains the "fat" binary should be a merge of the framework folders from the device and simulator builds.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061496/combined-framework-simulator-device-binary-xcode-7-3) solves it