# Swift framework into Objective-C device and simulator architectures

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, swift3

Gotta **weird** problem here. I built a dynamic framework called: **TestFramework**

I am able to successfully import TestFramework framework into my Objective-C app. However, it is only able to build for either the device architectures or the simulator architectures.

**How can I set it so that I can run my Objective-C app using this swift framework for any architecture?**

Right now, I achieve either architecture by deleting the framework from the app, rebuild the .framework file (chose either device or simulator) then re-deploy this framework into the app project. It's rather annoying to do this since I want to be able to use this framework in any project (simulator or device).

I am able to use **CocoaPods** but I haven't set this up yet.

In the framework I have a class called: "**Testing**" (see way below in the question). I am able to access this class in my objective-c app. Instantiate a "Testing" object, call it's public functions or whatever. Code compiles! However, the issue is I get an **error** when I try to build for the architecture that the framework wasn't compiled for. **The error:**

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/kersan/projects/TestApp2/TestApp2/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/kersan/projects/TestApp2/TestApp2/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC13TestFramework7Testing", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is a screenshot of my configs and some code:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

TestFramework.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for TestFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double TestFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for TestFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char TestFrameworkVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <TestFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

Testing.swift:

```
//
//  Testing.swift
//  TestFramework
//
//

import Foundation


@objc open class Testing : NSObject {
    
    open var testDescription : String?
    
    
    open func printDesc() -> String {
        print("testDescription: \(testDescription)")
        return "Testing class -> Hello World"
    }
    
}
```

ViewController in my Objective-C app:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  TestApp2
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestFramework/TestFramework-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    Testing *testing = [[Testing alloc] init];
    [testing printDesc];
    
    [_label setText:testing.printDesc];
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see - you builds framework for ios device but crash seems appears when trying run project on Simulator. Simulator has different architecture than device. So as for me crash because your framework doesn't contain symbols for simulator architecture (x86_64). So you just need to add this architecture to your framework. How to do this good explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270427/436694).

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction and solved my issue using an Aggregate target. I haven't submitted the framework to the appstore or an app with this framework in it to the appstore yet though. Hopefully that will work as explained in those answers too. Thanks!