# Custom Swift framework not exposing classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, frameworks

I made a custom Swift framework to reuse the same code across different projects. However, when I import the framework in other projects, the classes are not available for use.

**Things I already did**

1. To create the framework, I picked a Cocoa Touch Framework project. 
   The structure of the project:
   [framework project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHY2U.png)
2. I marked the classes `public class AVSManager {}` and the `init()` functions as public.
3. Copied the .framework file to the root of the other projects
4. In the projects, I added the framework as embedded binary
5. Imported the framework in the `ViewController.swift` class of a project: `import AVSCMDI`

When I then try to call `AVSManager()` it produces the following error: `AVSManager is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class`

Does anybody have an idea what i'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution to my problem!

It turned out that I needed to build my framework with a real device as target.

Comment: Ughh had the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any workaround to use the framework when running the application on simulator (except building the framework for an simulator and importing it then into project)?

Comment: Can anyone explain/understand this? I can't manage to compile the project (when I add a custom library) for a simulator..

Comment: You need to create a "fat" framework, for both architectures (simulator and real device). Take a look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device/29650369#29650369

Comment: had the same issue, Thanks !!