# Custom Framework using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift

So We are creating a framework which uses cocoa-pods dependency  for using dependencies .

```
 pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
```

When I am creating the framework and including in the project, its giving imageNotFound issue for  Socket.IO  framework.

We are not going to upload this framework  in cocoa-pods, its for internal distribution .

I saw few answers that we have to use podspecs..But I am confused in that.

Please show me the right path.

Comment: Will it be hosted in your private repository or somewhere locally to the project?

Comment: We will share .framework file with our client.

Comment: If you are sharing the '.framework' file yourself within your private network then it has nothing to do with cocoapod. You have to build a fat binary (framework supporting all the arcitectures) for sharing. try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634466/how-to-export-fat-cocoa-touch-framework-for-simulator-and-device