# CocoaPods podspec push without build simulator architecture

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I built a podspec using `vendored_libraries` to contain third party libraries which are just built for real device. Then I pushed the podspec file and got error which said cocoapods could not found symbols for architecture i386 and x86_64 ,because the libraries really had not the symbols for simulator architecture . So, can I push the podspec without build for the simulator architecture type? How to do ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this help you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26691080/6124910 Good luck

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5472

So, I asked an Issue about this question and got the answer.

**Cocoapods do not encourage restricting architectures.**

I manually manager the podspecs in my private pods repo instead of using `pod repo push` command.

Comment: So basically you've manually pused the Podspec in your private repo?

Answer (score 2):

You may pass `--skip-import-validation` (Lint skips validating that the pod can be imported) to `lint` or `push` command:

```sh
pod lib lint --skip-import-validation

pod trunk push --skip-import-validation --allow-warnings
```