# Swift framework creation and usage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Using Xcode 9.1 I am trying to create to start level simple framework in swift and use the same in objective c or swift proj. But I am getting a compilation while using it in app. Tried several tutorials and followed same steps as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSwbun3UV6U.. But no result.Defines Module is enabled.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide also information about error.

Comment: <unknown>:0: error: cannot load module 'SwifT' as 'Swift'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this remove framework **Quit** Xcode and re open your project add framework then **Clean and Build**. or **Clean folder and Build**. **Quit** project again and re-open it and **Build**

Also you should build framework for both iOS device and simulator architecture there is a run script to achieve this, [Run Script](https://gist.github.com/cromandini/1a9c4aeab27ca84f5d79), and check out how to run this script in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26691080/5611425)

Comment: I tried all this. First attempt i tried with run script itself

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your framework, it might be clashing with `swift` as error indicates `cannot load module 'SwifT' as 'Swift'`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you've followed the steps listed here: [Embedding a Framework in iOS, macOS, watchOS, and tvOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-EMBED_IN_APP_SECTION)

It should be very straightforward. If all else fails, remove the framework from your project and follow the steps again.