# Using xcodebuild to build different platform

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a framework project and I'm trying to build a fat file (iphoneos + iphonesimulator) using a script build phase, but it's not working. The script is simple; it checks the platform being currently built, like to:

```
if [[ "$SF_SDK_PLATFORM" = "iphoneos" ]]
then
SF_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
else
SF_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphoneos
fi
```

And then uses xcodebuild to build it:

```
xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -sdk ${SF_OTHER_PLATFORM} -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
```

Other details on the script have been omited for simplicity.

If I chose the initial target as the simulator, this works fine, and both the simulator and device binaries are generated and I use lipo to get the fat file. The problem happens when I do it the other way around, and build the device file, and as such xcodebuild is called for the iphonesimulator SDK. The build fails with the following error:

```
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
```

If I change the `-sdk` option I get the build, but not the simulator build, which is what I need. This would be (kinda) fine, but in order to build for release (Archive) I need to set the device as the primary target, or otherwise xcode doesn't give me the option.

What should I do?

Comment: from someone that is new to xcode... can't you use an if for the -sdk part? that might solve your problem

Comment: What do you mean? What would the if do?

Comment: my idea was (don't know if its possible) when you run, if its by simulator you have one code running (the -skd one) and if its iphoneos you run the other. again, really new to xcode and don't know if its possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to put your script in an aggregate target type. [It was designed for exactly such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747499/when-and-how-to-use-aggregate-target-in-xcode-4): two different targets in one build.

What I do is **create a new target** (Other->Aggregate type) and add a script to it and use that target to create a fat release product.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release

mkdir -p ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../MyApp${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}

cp -r ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../Release-iphoneos/ ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../MyApp${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}

lipo -create "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../Release-iphoneos/MyApp.framework/MyApp" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.framework/MyApp" -output "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../MyApp${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}/MyApp.framework/MyApp"
```

Works like a charm. It creates a folder with the version number (you set it in your new target) and a fat framework inside.

EDIT:

Why this didn't work for you.

> Developer is free to distribute iOS framework without codesigning it
>   as Consumer will re-codesign it anyway, but Developer is forced by
>   Xcode to codesign his framework when he builds for iOS device.

[Creating iOS/OSX Frameworks: is it necessary to codesign them before distributing to other developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963294/creating-ios-osx-frameworks-is-it-necessary-to-codesign-them-before-distributin)

When you're using the device target *you're forced to code sign* even if you don't have to. That's why it works with the aggregate target -> it's not expected of you to codesign and you don't need to codesign to release a framework.

Comment: Is this an External Build System target ?

Comment: Other -> Aggregate target

Comment: Hmm.. It builds, but I only get `armv7` and `arm64` with `lipo -info`. Is it not joining the simulator version?

Comment: What folder are you checking ? You should have a folder like ".../Products/MyProduct1.0.0" - that's where the script is putting the fat framework.

Comment: lipo.....
 -*output* "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../MyApp${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}/MyApp.framework/MyApp"

Comment: Nevermind! I was on the right folder, but it's now generating `i386` and `x86_64` as well! Thanks

Comment: Just one more thing, this is copying the folder structure from the iphoneos folder, which includes the Info.plist file with configurations for that architecture. Should I delete that file?

Comment: Yes, I always delete that file. I need to add this step to my script ;)

Comment: I've foud an answer why this happens to you. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: ("you may award your bounty in 22 hours" :P)

Comment: Hmm, actually the "why" part makes sense. Although unfortunate from Apple's end

Comment: What about the _CodeSignature folder, do you also delete that?

Comment: Yep :D haha next step for my script.

Comment: Awesome! ;) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually, deleting those folders is not working for me. I get `App installation failed: Could not inspect application package` when deploying in an app. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't think it's connected in any way, it' something else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249441/app-installation-failed-could-not-inspect-application-package

Comment: I think it's the wrong character in project name. You're probably using "André Fratelli" somewhere in your project :D "é" is the problem.

Comment: It only happens after deleting the Info.plist file =\ It works without deleting it

Comment: Thats interesting. I know why though. I'm using it as a static library, youre using it as a dynamic library. Keep the info.plisf for the device then - I dont see why not.

Comment: Dynamic library frameworks are probably copied into the .app bundle and every bundle that gets copied gets validated -> it needs info.plist... Jeeeez, apple...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97337/discussion-between-michal-ciurus-and-andre-fratelli).

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the simulator, the process works fine because you are building using the Debug configuration I think.

In the Project navigator, select your project. Now select your target and under the Build Settings tab, check `Code Signing Identity` settings.

If you expand that, you should see a row for every configuration you set in your project (if you didn't, you should see the default Debug and Release rows).

Now check under the Release row (that is the default used when the Archive command is called) that is set the correct identity (this is based on what you selected under Provisioning Profile).

If you want to know more about provisioning profiles, signing identity and so on, check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) from Apple